# Android flavour and how it works

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I need to get this clarified. Lets say i have a main folder that has its own source directory and resource directory. I also have Flavour1 and Flavour2 that both have they're own source and resource directory. If i have a image called banner.png in the main resource folder.

Will that image be replace when i run build Variant Flavour1 if that flavour has that image in its own resource directory.

Or should i build up my project so that the banners is in Flavour1 and Flavour2 but not in the main resource folder?

I have read: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide and this helped a lot. But there is something i have missed since my Flavour setup dont work properly.

Comment: Please check this, https://github.com/izBasit/ProductFlavorDemo

I had done something long back similar to what you want.

As far as my understanding goes, if you put banner in main, and you override with image banner in flavor1. When you build your app by selecting flavor1, then banner from flavor1 will be selected.

Comment: Thanks. i have a guess over why my flavours dont work now. I will write back if i find a solution

Comment: It is as iZBasit said. It overrides the old image. I made a bobo. My gradle setup was correct. I just did not know that the device i tested on was xxhdpi.

Comment: demo for the same pls check http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-studio-flavors-demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will that image be replace when i run build Variant Flavour1 if that flavour has that image in its own resource directory.

If you have `src/main/res/drawable-XXXX/banner.png` and `src/flavor1/res/drawable-XXXX/banner.png` (each for some value of `XXXX`), and you build `flavor1`, you should get the `flavor1` edition of `banner.png`.

> Or should i build up my project so that the banners is in Flavour1 and Flavour2 but not in the main resource folder?

You can override resources and assets. You cannot override Java code, so if you had `src/main/java/some/package/here/Foo.java` and `src/flavor1/java/some/package/here/Foo.java`, you will have a compile error.

Comment: In case it fails the first time, clean the project and retry.